# How to enable sbt plugins of root project for all subprojects?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a `project/build.scala` file that defines a root project and a bunch of sub projects:

```
lazy val root = Project(
  id="root",
  base=file(".")).aggregate(subA, subB).enablePlugins(MyPlugin)

lazy val subA = Project(
  id="subA",
  base=file("a"))

lazy val subB = Project(
  id="subB",
  base=file("b"))
```

How do I make `MyPlugin` available in `subA` and `subB` without specifying it on each of them? I just want them to inherit the plugins from the `root` project.

Answer (score 2):

Someone in IRC suggested overriding `projects` in my build object in build.scala:

```
override def projects = super.projects map { _.enablePlugins(...) }
```